# Limit of a Continuous and Monotone Function of a Stochastic Process

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I have been struggling with this limit, which is a part of a project, for a week now.
Suppose we have a stochastic process, $S_t$, Such that $\lim_{t\longrightarrow\infty}S_t/t \longrightarrow y$, where $y $ is a random variable.
I could find the random variable, but then along with the calculations, I got the function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x-1/2(1+\tanh(2(x-a))),
\end{equation}
which is strictly monotone and continuous ( $a$ is a fixed number ). I need to calculate
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\longrightarrow \infty }\frac{f(S_t)}{t}.
\end{equation}
Is there any way to use the limit of $S_t/t$, y, when calculating $\lim_{t\longrightarrow \infty }\frac{f(S_t)}{t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\tanh(x)|\le 1$,
$$
|f(S_t)/t-y|\le |S_t/t-y|+t^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake by using the same parameters, x, for both limit of the process and the definition of the function, I edite that. I guess your answer is based on that!

Comment: You mean, I can simply consider S instead of f ( asymptotically ) ?

Comment: @kepler Yes, the second term of $f(S_t)/t$ is asymptotically negligible.

Comment: thank you so much.